# How to solve null issue in resources field of service activity?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

when I insert a systemuser to Resources look up field on service activity  entity save and open it again I find a null value added. I didn't find an explanation about that issue or how to solve it, anyone ?
[image]

Comment: Is this happening in all your instances like dev, prod? I would try in vanilla crm to make sure this is not bcoz of your customizations.

Comment: @ArunVinoth I did the vanilla crm (without my custom view) and it still happens when I googled it I found that other programmers had that issue but no solution

Comment: You can reach out to MS support for this issue - https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/198077/null-value-getting-added-when-adding-a-new-resource-in-service-activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a MS Product bug and probably limited to a particular version. We can find similar community [forum thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/198077/null-value-getting-added-when-adding-a-new-resource-in-service-activity) discussion on this topic.

You can create a ticket with MS support, they can advise you some hotfix solution patch or workaround.